# Installing Windows on 100+ cluster nodes?

Tags: installation, cluster-computing

I have a cluster server which consists of 100 nodes with CentOS installed currently. For some reasons (however bad it is :<), I need to install Windows 8.1 over them.

I am going to install Windows 8.1 on a node and set up the softwares needed. 
Can I make a ghost image from it and distribute over the other nodes to install it? Is there any one who have a similar experience?

thanks :D